# How to set core dump naming scheme without su/sudo?

Tags: multithreading, gdb, mpi, coredump

I am developing a MPI program on a Linux machine where I do not have sudo/su access. As my program currently segfaults, I would like to examine the core dumps via gdb. Unfortunately, as the program is multi-threaded, all the threads write to one core dump. So I would like to be able to append the PID to each separate core dump for every process.

I know there is a way to do it via /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern, however I do not have access to write to this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Multithreading has nothing to do with your problem (GDB can handle core files containing multiple threads just fine). Your problem is that you have multi-process program. What I don't understand is why a single 'core' is not enough for you -- presumably your other processes crash the same way. Even if they don't, you should fix the first problem (found in the first core) before proceeding to fix the next.

Comment: @Employed Russian:  One process hitting a segfault does not imply that any other process would also segfault.

Comment: @semiuseless That is true, but even if they don't, you should fix the first problem you see *anyway*. So one core dump is enough for you to have something to fix!

Answer (score 1):

It can be a pain to debug MPI apps on systems that are configured this way when you do not have root access.  One option for working around this is to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to get stack traces for your segfault(s).  This will only be useful provided that your application will fail in a reasonable period of time when slowed down via Valgrind, and that it still segfaults at all in this case.

I usually run MPI apps under Valgrind like this:

```
% mpiexec -n 5 valgrind -q /path/to/my_app
```

That will send all of the Valgrind output to standard error.  But if I want the output separated into different files, then you can get a bit fancier:

```
% mpiexec -n 5 valgrind -q --log-file='vg_out.%q{PMI_RANK}' /path/to/my_app
```

That's the setup for MPICH2.  I think that for Open MPI you'll need to replace `PMI_RANK` with `OMPI_MCA_ns_nds_vpid`, but if that doesn't work for you then you'll need to check with the Open MPI developers on their discussion list.  In either case, this will yield N files, where N is the size of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, each named `vg_out.0`, `vg_out.1`, ..., to `vg_out.$(($N-1))`, each corresponding to a rank in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: For OpenMPI the variable to use would be `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK`, and for Cray systems, `ALPS_APP_PE`. Note also that `PMI_RANK` also works for Intel MPI (which is based on MPICH)